# Using CSS to set absolute position of div

Tags: css, windows-8

I am creating an application on Windows 8 that allows horizontal scroll. What I want to do is make a div be fixed relative to the actual width and height of the app, NOT my screen. Right now the div scrolls when I scroll, but I want it to stay put. I thought `position:absolute;` tells a div to be positioned relative to its parent, but it is not doing this. I checked to make sure the parent div was fixed and it is using `float:left;`. Any idea what is going on? Here is some code.

```
#parentDiv {
    height: 720px;
    width: 1366px;
    float: left;
}
#div {
    height: 60%;
    width: 15%;
    top: 200px;
    right: 2.5%;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 25px;
    opacity:0;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give your div position fixed ... Absolute is not going to help.

```
position: fixed;
```

Answer (score 4):

position: fixed for the div. Needn't care about the parentDiv